# Delete nested object with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I got this mongoose schemas:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  groups: [
    {
      groupName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      groupMembers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "GroupMember" }],
    },
  ],
});


const GroupMemberSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    birthday: Date,
    gender: String,
    age: Number
});
```

I want to have 2 routes:

- Delete a group member from the `groupMembers` array based on objectId.
- Delete a whole group from the `groups` array based on objectId.

My attempt for the delete group member route. This route removes the group member from the `groupMembers` collection succesfully, but the group member still exist in the `user` collection:

```
router.delete(
  "/:userId/:groupId/:groupMemberId",
  catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const { userId, groupId, groupMemberId } = req.params;
    await GroupMember.findByIdAndDelete(groupMemberId);
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const group = user.groups.find((group) => group._id.toString() === groupId);
    const groupIndex = user.groups.indexOf(group);
    const updatedGroupmembers = user.groups[groupIndex].groupMembers.filter(groupMember=> groupMember._id.toString()!==groupMemberId);
    res.send({updatedGroupmembers})
  })
);
```

Comment: can you provide groupmembers schema?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using $pull?

```js
router.delete(
  '/:userId/:groupId/:groupMemberId',
  catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const { userId, groupId, groupMemberId } = req.params;
    await GroupMember.findByIdAndDelete(groupMemberId);
    const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ id: userId }, { $pull: { groups: groupId } }, { new: true });
    res.send({ updatedUser });
  }),
);
```

Comment: Ok, did'nt know about the $pull, so this line will delete the whole group that the group member is inside of, right? if i want to delete only the group member from the user I need to write `$pull: { groups.groupMembers: groupMemberId }` ?